# Calendar issue when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datepicker

The datepicker does not open in my app. Could you please help me? When I click, the openCalendar function is executing, but the datepicker does not open at all.

```
openCalendar = e => {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
this._calendar.setOpen(true);

console.log(this._calendar);
};
```

I have this code in return {

```
          {/* DATEPICKER */}
      <div className={cx(s.dtpicker, step ? overlay.legField : null)} ref={el => (this.dtpicker = el)}>
        <div className={s.dateClicker} onClick={this.openCalendar} />
        <Calendar color="#A8AAB7" />

        <DatePicker
          ref={c => (this._calendar = c)}
          selected={leg.date || this.getToday()}
          onChange={(d) => this.updateDate(d, index)}
          minDate={this.today}
          autoFocus={false}
          readOnly={true}

          /*open={true}*/

          shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
          locale={currentLocale}
          showTimeSelect
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          timeIntervals={30}
          dateFormat="ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"
          popperPlacement="bottom-center"
          popperModifiers={{
            preventOverflow: {
              enabled: true,
              escapeWithReference: false, // force popper to stay in viewport (even when input is scrolled out of view)
              boundariesElement: 'viewport'
            }
          }}
        />

      </div>
```

I can provide more details if needed to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you receive any error(s) in your developer console?

Comment: Hi, no errors in console. After clicking the setOpen property is true.

Comment: Can you please try moving `e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();` lines after your `this._calendar.setOpen(true);` statement and see if it works?

Comment: I moved those two lines but still nothing.

Comment: It only shows up when open={true}.